# Node ID is missing in contextual filters

Tags: views, nodes

The node ID is missing in the view contextual filters.

> [image]

How can I use the node ID as contextual filter?

Comment: It's just _ID_, in the _Content_ category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot you show, it's *Identifiant (ID)*, the third rown of the *Contenu* category (*Catégorie* in the screenshot).

Since the context filters have a category, the node ID is simply called *Identifier* or *ID*. There isn't any possibility to confuse it with other IDs, like the user ID, because other IDs have a different category. You cannot even confuse it with the revision ID (*Identifiant (ID) de révision*) or the UUID (*Identifiant universel unique (UUID)*).

Comment: Thank kiamlaluno, node ID has been removed in the latest version.Your answer works well